# The spheres operad

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

I have a rather naive question.  Consider the space of all maps

$$ S^{j_1} \times S^{j_2} \times \cdots \times S^{j_k} \to S^n $$

for all possible natural numbers $n, k, j_1, \cdots , j_k$.

This collection is a fairly standard example of a coloured operad, in that there are many composition maps and they satisfy an associativity and identity axiom.

Is there much written up about this operad in the algebraic topology literature?  I imagine there are many things known about this operad, but they're mostly written up in other languages -- like secondary homotopy operations.  I'm interested in what is known about this operad and if it offers any enlightenment into the homotopy groups of spheres.  Or perhaps there is a structure theorem for this operad, saying that its homotopy-type is in some sense determined by homotopy groups of spheres and various higher homotopy operations.

It's a bit of a vague question but anything fairly informative will be considered an answer in my books.

Comment: "Homotopy operations" seems like the wrong thing to say - the morphisms here describe "co-homotopy operations" or something like that. "Homotopy operations" should correspond to taking wedge sums and not products, right?

Comment: For Qiaochu's homotopy operations, you should also reverse the direction of the maps to get something nontrivial (maps $S^a\vee S^b\to S^c$ are easy but maps $S^c\to S^a\vee S^b$ are hard, and it is also the latter that give natural transformations $\pi_a\times\pi_b\to\pi_c$).  [Hilton proved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilton%27s_theorem) all such operations are generated by the homotopy groups of spheres and the Whitehead product.

Comment: Except that they work with based spheres, the paper ``The sphere operad'' by Gregory Arone and Marja Kankaanrinta may give (or can be adapted to give) what you ask for.  It is available at:

http://pi.math.virginia.edu/~zga2m/SphereOperad.pdf

Comment: @Peter: at a first glance, that paper doesn't seem relevant. It considers an uncolored operad whose spaces parameterizing operations are spheres, whereas here there is a colored operad such that the spaces parameterizing operations are mapping spaces between products of spheres.

Comment: Here's a more general (but still vague) question. If we are in a symmetric monoidal category with internal Homs, then for any object $X$ there is an operad $\{\mathrm{Hom}(X^{\otimes n},X)\}$, and for any collection $X_i$, $i \in I$, of objects there is a similar $I$-colored endomorphism operad. These tautologically defined operads are used all the time in order to define the notion of $X$ being a $P$-algebra for some $P$.

Comment: Are there *any* other nontrivial uses of this construction? (E.g. a nontrivial presentation of such an operad, a theorem about the Hom-spaces proved most naturally in the language of operads, etc.)

Comment: For the version with wedges, this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403098 shows that it assembles into a theory and provides "yet another delooping machine".

Comment: @Dan: lots! For example, suppose $F$ is the forgetful functor from some category $C$ to sets (as an object of the functor category, with the cartesian monoidal structure). Then the endomorphism operad of $F$ is the operad of $n$-ary operations on objects of $C$ regarded as sets with extra structure in the way prescribed by $F$. Another name for this gadget is a Lawvere theory, and in familiar cases $C$ is in fact the category of models of the Lawvere theory.

Comment: @Dan: see http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/operations-and-lawvere-theories/, http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/operations-pro-objects-and-grothendiecks-galois-theory/ and maybe http://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/operations-pro-objects-and-grothendiecks-galois-theory/ for details and some variations on this theme.

Comment: @Dan: More examples: as Eric Wofsey says, the corresponding (colored) operad involving the spheres but in the opposite of the homotopy category defines homotopy operations, and a presentation of these is known (in terms of the homotopy groups of spheres). Studying the corresponding colored operad involving the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces defines cohomology operations and these are a huge industry. So it seems bizarre to me to talk as if this construction only has one use.